# How to define new function with get set in Fragment inherited class

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to use a tabbed ActionBar and using Fragments for this. I want to add a simple function in my newsFragment class (inherited from Fragment) for setting and getting a tabIndex value. But it looks like the new function doesn't exist in my new class.

Here's the code there I try to use the new class:

```
Fragment frag = new newsFragment ();
frag.tabIndex = 0; // <--- I'm getting an error here
```

And here's my class:

```
namespace NApp
{
    public class newsFragment : Fragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.NewsFragmentTemplate, null);
            return view;
        }
      public int tabIndex { get; set; }      
    }
}
```

It works if I make a complete new class:

```
namespace NApp
{
    public class test
    {
        public test () {}
        public int tabIndex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Anyone that can help?

Comment: You say you're getting an error. **What** error? Your code looks fine.

Comment: Welcome from Java... use "var frag = new NewsFragment ();" :) notice Capital News :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
Fragment frag = new newsFragment ();
```

to

```
newsFragment frag = new newsFragment ();
```